# Do getRequestDispatcher(), getOutputStream() and getWriter() have some relationship?

Tags: java, exception, servlets, stream, printwriter

I have this snippet of my working code

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");

        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        request.getRequestDispatcher("link.html").include(request, response);


        String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
        String passWord = request.getParameter("passWord");
```

I don't have any problem with this code, it works the way I wanted it to do. But if I exchange the places of my getWriter() and getRequestDispatcher() an IllegalArgumentException is displayed.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");

        request.getRequestDispatcher("link.html").include(request, response);
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();

        String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
        String passWord = request.getParameter("passWord");

java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:614)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:199)
    com.servlet.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:34)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
```

It says that `getOutputStream()` has already been called. I have been searching this exception but I don't see any proper explanation with my current situation.

These are my assumptions(please correct me if I am wrong)

1. `getRequestDispatcher()` calls `getOutputStream()` implicitly, and if you call the `getWriter()` method the exception will be displayed because `getOutputStream()` and `getWriter() cannot be both called.
2. If the `getWriter()` method is called before the `getRequestDispatcher()` method, `getRequestDispatcher()` will use the returned `PrintWriter` object instead of calling `getOutputStream()`.

If all of my assumptions are wrong, can you tell me what is the correct relationship with these 3 methods?

Comment: I think you've got it pretty right.

Answer (score 0):

There **is a relationship between getOutputStream() and getWriter()**.

But, there **is no relationship between getRequestDispatcher()**.

The relationship between `getOutputStream()` and `getWriter()` is that during request processing you cannot use both of them. The reason is because, using both the methods would interleaves the data. It does not meet the ultimate requirement.

In your case, the `getRequestDispatcher()` is using `getOutputStream()` so you are unable to write using `getWriter()` later.

It could be otherwise also.